# Intellij IDEA HotSwap with Tomcat works for classes but not for JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat7, struts-1, intellij-14

I'm doing a war deployement (not exploded war) in Tomcat7 with IntelliJ IDEA 14.
My webapp is composed of 2 wars :

- *views.war* (Struts classes, JSP)
- *business.war* (Business, persistance and WS)

So my **CATALINA_HOME/webapps** contains :

- ROOT/
- *views*/
- *business*/

There contents are ok.

And my *CATALINA_BASE/work/catalina/localhost...* (overrided by IDEA) contains the generated servlets (_jsp.class + sources).

Curiously, if I make a change on a Java class of *views* and recompile (Ctrl+Maj+F9), my change takes effects immediatly. But if I make change on a JSP, I have to redeploy. Ctrl+Maj+F9 and HotSwap doesn't works.

After making the change in the JSP, I had seen that JSP file is modified in my **CATALINA_HOME/webapps** folder. But the java class (myJsp_jsp.java) in **CATALINA_BASE/work/catalina/localhost...** never changes until I restart the server or redeploy the application.

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understood **Hotswap uses JVM**. So it just works with Java classes.

I have to use **Exploded war** that directly uses files into Maven's target folder with a special config for my Tomcat. So Tomcat doesn't read webapps folder's files.

Comment: "with a special config for my Tomcat" can you elaborate on this please?